# Create FormArray from api Data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have data from an API, like this:

```
{ actions: 1, created_at: "2020-11-27 18:13:50", id: 18, payment: "0.00", change: "A" }
```

And I need to send back the data modified by user, I am using Reactive Forms for this, I am showing the data with Angular Material tables.

I have an idea that it would be more or less like this:

```
this.form = fB.group({data: this.fB.array( [fB.group({here.the.group}} )
```

How can I create the formArray from the data I receive dynamically? The idea is to be able to edit from the table and send the new formArray as the new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setValue` or `patchValue`, I like `patchValue` as it comes with fewer challenges in setting up

Lets say your data is like below

```json
  { 
    actions: 1, 
    created_at: "2020-11-27 18:13:50", 
    id: 18, 
    payment: "0.00", 
    change: "A",
    data: [
       { id: 1, name: 'item 2'},
       { id: 2, name: 'item 3'},
       { id: 3, name: 'Item 3'}
     ]
  }
```

You can implement below approach to set your form

```typescript
this.form = fB.group({
  actions: [''],
  payment: [''],
  change: [''],
  data: this.fb.array([])
})

get formDataArray() {
  return this.form.get('data') as FormArray
}
ngOnInit() {
   this.myService.getData().subscribe(({actions, payment, change, data })=> {
     this.form.patchValue({ actions, payment, change });
     data.forEach(({id, name})=> {
       this.formDataArray.push(
         this.fb.group({id: [id], name: [name] })
       )
     })
   })
}
```

Comment: thanks! i get the idea of formArray now. I would only have to pass the rows as data for the backend, each one individually. If it's not a problem, any idea of how you can pass the data of the form in this case? (I'm new to angular, sorry if the question is too basic)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question, what do you mean by 'pass the data of the form'

Comment: No problem! It was a matter of passing the data individually by ID, I got tangled up for a moment. Thanks for the help above, I appreciate it alot